# Suppressing autogenerated cruft when using Sphinx autodoc with a list-typed module data member

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, autodoc

I'm trying to use `sphinx.ext.autodoc` to document a module data member which is a list of objects of `SomeType`:

```
class SomeType(object):
    pass

Foo = SomeType()
Bar = SomeType()

foo_bar = [Foo, Bar]
```

My autodoc directive looks like:

```
.. autodata:: foo_bar
  :annotation: List[SomeType]

  Important documentation.
```

But the generated documentation contains autogenerated cruft. Where I expect to see the text:

`Important documentation.`

I instead see:

`list() -> new empty list list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable’s items Important documentation.`

How can I suppress this output?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

1. Add an empty ["documentation comment"](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autodata) (or an empty docstring) in the code:

   ```
   #: 
   foo_bar = [Foo, Bar]
   ```
2. Remove "Important documentation" from the `autodata` directive and put it in the special comment instead:

   ```
   #: Important documentation
   foo_bar = [Foo, Bar]
   ```

Comment: Interesting, I can't get the documentation comments/docstrings to work *at all* with autodata.

Comment: Sphinx 2.1.2 fwiw

Comment: I cannot explain why it does not work for you. When reproducing the problem (using Python 3.7.1 and Sphinx 2.2.1) I noticed that I did not get the same "cruft" as you did: *Built-in mutable sequence. If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty list. The argument must be an iterable if specified*.

Comment: yep, I've been building using python 3.6.8 -- this cruft is just the first line of `help(list)` for our respective versions

Comment: I wonder if it's possible that this is because of some unpleasant interaction with sphinx.ext.napoleon.

Comment: I don't know. For me it makes no difference if sphinx.ext.napoleon is enabled or disabled.